# NTFS Permission - Only allow owner of files/folder to delete the files/folder. Orther user can read/write but not delete

Tags: windows, ntfs, windows-server-2012

I try to create NTFS Permission that .nly allow owner of files/folder to delete the files/folder. Orther users can read/write but not delete. But i not able to do so. Can we do that on windows ? I'm using Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: This is done using Windows permissions on the folder and files in it.

Comment: Hi Moab, can you give me more detaild how to do it ? which option i should choose. Folder is ok but not files. Cause we usually have a lot of files, Cann't do on each files.